# Index pandas DataFrame with lists of indices and fill with value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two pandas DataFrames. `idxs` has indices with multiple `y` values for each `x`. I also have an 0-filled matrix called `mat` that holds all possible indices, like below:

```
idxs = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.repeat([1,4,20,50, 84],2), "y":np.random.randint(100, size=10)})
mat = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(100), columns=np.arange(100))
```

How do I most efficiently use the rows of `idxs` to fill in `mat` with 1s.

The best I've been able to do is capture them by row:

```
mat.loc[4, list(idxs.loc[lambda df: df['x'] == 4, "y"])] = 1
```

and then loop over the values in `x`. However, I want to avoid a mask over each value in `x`. I imagine there must be a way to index based on two lists of `x` and `y` values but I'm not able to find it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**: You can try your approach a bit faster with updating by groups:

```
for x,ys in idxs.groupby('x')['y']:
    mat.loc[x,ys] = 1
```

**Option 2**: Copy the whole data out, update using numpy indexing, and assign back:

```
data = mat.to_numpy()
data[idxs['x'], idxs['y']] = 1
mat.loc[:] = data
```